# Firebase admin Can't read property 'cert' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-admin, hapi

I writing a hapi backend api with firebase admin. I can't find a fix for this error.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'cert' of undefined
at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:109:37)
at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:133:24)`

Code:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import serviceAccount from './resources/serviceAccount.js'
let storageBucket = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '' : 'gs://myapp-dev.appspot.com'

let app = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "https://myapp.firebaseio.com" : "https://jointcreative1-dev.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Package json:

```
 {
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Hapi/joi backend server",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "XXX",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/hapi": "^19.1.1",
    "firebase": "^7.14.6",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.12.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.4.1",
    "google-auth-library": "^0.12.0",
    "hapi-auth-jwt2": "^10.1.0"
  }
}
```

I was using it in sapper and everything worked fine but moving into hapi broke it for some reason.

This was addressed a few years ago but multiple major versions have been released since then.

Answer (score 16):

As written in package.json as `"type":" module"`

It looks like you are using ES Modules,
so try the following:

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. What is beyond me is why it worked with "*as admin" on dev but not on production being every config equal....

Comment: To highlight the difference ... don't use import * as

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one?

```js
var serviceAccount = require('./resources/serviceAccount.js');
let app = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by riversun (thanks btw), I had the same issue and all I had to do is to change:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
```

To:

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
```